# How to apply "hover" and "visited" styles to a hyperlink within an existing style in an external css page in asp.net

Tags: css

I would like to apply styles such as this for hyperlinks :

```
a:link {
color: lightsteelblue;
text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {
color: black;
text-decoration:none;}
```

However have it within a existing style on the css sheet.
e.g

```
.menuitems {
padding-top: 13px;
margin-right : 30px;
a:hover 
color: black;
text-decoration:none;}
```

Is there any possible way of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.menuitems a:link{color: lightsteelblue;text-decoration:none}
.menuitems a:hover{color: black; text-decoration:none}
```

Your question should be tagged as css.

Comment: Your right. It should now that you mention it. Thank you so much though this works perfectly